# Is this script resource intensive? If so, how do one improve?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a simple script that turns a saw blade in my game. The problem is there is approx 18 active blades on the scene, at a time. I am trying to eliminate any probability of lag. This made me wonder if using such a script in "Update", can cause lag?

```
public class SawBladesRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool GameOver;
    public GameObject Player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameOver = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().GameOver; 
        if(GameOver == false)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -45) * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks fine as you only rotate a game object. Only thing please use if(!gameOver) instead of gameOver==false. Just looks way cleaner and is the norm for handling bools.

Comment: @MirkoBrandt Ok thank you! I was unaware that "gameOver == false can be "!gameOver". So using scripts is okay on performance, even though animation is an alternative?

Comment: It really depends. With a real animation you could do much more advanced things but if you just want to rotate up to 18 objects you should not have any performance issues. I did a small games with hundreds of dynamically created objects that where moving and rotating around in the map and didn't have any performance issues

Comment: repeat calls to the getcomponent would seem unnecessary, but other than that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on top of the `Start` method as class field

```
private PlayerController playerController;
```

and this into `Start`:

```
playeController = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>()
```

Then re-use the reference:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(playerController.GameOver) return;

    //...
}
```

The rest is fine but ofcourse it always depends completely on your usecase.

Even more efficient it would be to directly reference the Component within unity:

```
[SerializeField] private PlayerController playerController;
```

Now you can simply drag&drop the Player GameObject into that field in the Inspector and can get rid of the `GetComponent` call.